# XSL: let raw HTML through

Tags: html, xslt

Im making a XSL transform. The XML I'm transforming has a  node which contains html.

```
<xml>
    <text>
        <p><b>Hello</b><em>There</em></p>
    </text>
</xml>
```

Applying the transform:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <div class="{name()} input">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the output:

```
<div class="text input">
    Hello There
</div>
```

But I want the Html to remain intact like so:

```
<div class="text input">
    <p><b>Hello</b><em>There</em></p>
</div>
```

Substituting *.* with the *node()* function gives the same result.

Is there a method of getting the HTML through the transform unmodified?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [xsl:copy-of](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_copy-of.asp)

It should do what you need..

```
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
```

The above will select the whole current node so in your case the `<text>` itself will be included..

Use the following to select everything under the current..

```
<xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
```

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` would copy the entire `<text>` node, not just its contents. ;)

Comment: Oh by the way: the child axis is implicit. This means `<xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />` and `<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />` are equivalent.

Comment: Do not forget to set the output method="html - or you might not get the desired result.